# Display selections count in textbox from dropdown checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to display selections count in textbox from dropdown checkboxes, how this can be done?

[image]

[image]

```js
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
$("input[type='text'"]).val("All fruits")
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <input type="text" class="form-control dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" value="2 Fruits selected" aria-expanded="false" data-bs-auto-close="outside" readonly>
    <div class="dropdown-menu p-0">
      <div class="list-group">
        <label class="list-group-item">
          <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" value=""> Fruit1 </label>
        <label class="list-group-item">
          <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" value=""> Fruit2 </label>
        <label class="list-group-item">
          <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" value=""> Fruit3 </label>
        <label class="list-group-item">
          <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" value=""> Fruit4 </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `change` listener, get the number of checked checkboxes by using the `checked` pseudo-class. Then, just compare the length of the selected elements list:

```js
const totalLength = $('input[type="checkbox"]').length

$(':checkbox').change(function() {
  const checked = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length
  $("input[type='text']").val(checked == totalLength ? "All fruits" : `${checked} Fruits selected`)
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <input type="text" class="form-control dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" value="2 Fruits selected" aria-expanded="false" data-bs-auto-close="outside" readonly>
    <div class="dropdown-menu p-0">
      <div class="list-group">
        <label class="list-group-item">
          <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" value=""> Fruit1 </label>
        <label class="list-group-item">
          <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" value=""> Fruit2 </label>
        <label class="list-group-item">
          <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" value=""> Fruit3 </label>
        <label class="list-group-item">
          <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" value=""> Fruit4 </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much but I cannot hard code as 4, is there a way to determine dynamically?

Comment: In real world sceanrio it may be much higher and the number is not known beforehand

Comment: @CodeGuy OK. I've updated my answer. It should work with any length now.